# Incorrect number of shards returned from REST API call

Tags: weaviate

I can see in the "shardingConfig" returned from the GET v1/schema REST API call that I have 10 shards. This makes sense since I am running Weaviate in an EKS cluster with 10 replicas.

However, when I call GET v1/schema/${class_name}/shards, I get a single shard.

Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue @Fabrizio, the Weaviate team is looking into it…

Comment: You can track this here: https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/2145